# How to show that $f(x) = \frac{1-acosx}{1-2a cosx+a^{2}}$ can be expressed as $C(\frac{1}{1-ae^{ix}} +\frac{1}{1-ae^{-ix}})$?

Tags: complex-numbers

This only works for a particular constant $C$ and one must find that as well. Though, I know it involves Euler's formula, I'm not sure how to begin this one.

How to show that $f(x) = \dfrac{1 - a \cos x}{1 - 2 a \cos x + a^{2}}$ can be expressed as $C \left( \frac{1}{1 - a e^{ix}} +\frac{1}{1-ae^{-ix}} \right)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim: $\frac{1-a\cos x}{1-2a \cos x+a^{2}} =C\left(\frac{1}{1-ae^{ix}} +\frac{1}{1-ae^{-ix}}\right)$.

Hint: make a common denominator on the right hand side and use $\cos x = \frac12 (e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$.